# Redis nosql scan function malfunction

Tags: redis

I am trying to get a key using the scan function

Look at the screenshot

When searching with keys, the ticker key is normally brought in

Why can't I search when I search with scan?

When searching for a user with scan, it is normally searched. What is the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scan with *ticker**, Redis returns an empty result with a cursor larger than 0. That means the first scan, i.e. Redis checks a bunch of keys, does not find any keys matching the pattern. It does NOT mean that there's no key matching the pattern.

So you need to call scan again with the cursor returned by Redis to scan some more keys, until the returned cursor is 0. Check the [scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan/) doc for detail.